# Django: insert multiple input text and file

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have recently tried to learn Django and I want to know it's possible to insert multiple input with this form structure to table database? if it's possible, can you tell me how it is? Thank you!!!

```
<form class="log-in" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if include model.py and views.py it wiil become more easy to answer your question

Comment: What you are looking for are formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @hendrikschneider hey there I tried to implementation your suggestion and now i can insert multiple data with formset. Thank you !!!

Comment: @ZaqiSalmanAlexa Nice that you were able to solve it. I posted my recommendation as answer and I would be nice if you would accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are formsets: docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets